# Set common background for all components in Angular 6

Tags: angular, css, background

I am trying to get a background (comprising an image and colour) to be on all the components, and have put the code for it in styles.css. It appears on the main AppComponent page, but any other components that are rendered appear on top of that and cover the background with a white background of their own. So for now I am applying the background to every component and adjusting the top positioning.

Is there any easier, more efficient way to do this?

Here's some of the CSS code that I'm applying in my components.

**a.component.css**

```
.bg {
   background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) url('src/assets/images/background.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 60% -312px;
   background-size: 2874px 818px;
}
```

**b.component.css**

```
.bg {
   background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1) url('src/assets/images/background.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 60% -482px;
   background-size: 2874px 818px;
}
```

Comment: You can put this css in the general `style.css`, so every component will look at this file to find its configuration

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have, but every component overlaps and covers the background. Also, since there are different components over and below each other, I'm having to adjust the height positioning for each one of them.

Comment: Try `@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})`
With ViewEncapsultion.None, adding rules to CSS file that’s tied to a component is the equivalent to adding the same rules to a global styles.css file.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Okay, I tried that and it worked. So I should put the background class in every component html, and just adjust the height in the component's css, with all the other properties being fetched from styles.css, right?
Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: @AkashSrivastav Yep, that's gonna do the trick!

Comment: @JacopoSciampi So is there no way where I do not have to put it in every component's html and having to adjust the height? Any way to make them not hide the bg?

Comment: Well you can assign dinamically the `bg-position` using `ngStyle`, but since every component has it's own position, I believe you have to calc it for every component via `.ts`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a node app in that case you can just set background for your main.handlebars file. And the other pages will render it from the main layout view.

would look a bit like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>background-color: #color_id</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  {{{body}}}
 </body>
</html>
```